# How environment variables can be read from a file when going into a login shell with here-string and using the sudo command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, sudo

I am trying to write a small script that aims to login to a remote server, load environment variables and print one of them. (In the actual script, instead of an `echo`, the parameters that are read are to be used. For the sake of simplicity here I am using just `echo`.)

The structure of the script and the commands that I tried are as follows but unfortunately none succeeds:

```sh
ssh -i lightsail.pem ubuntu@production <<< '
  sudo echo $TEST_PARAMETER
  sudo sh -c "~/Environment/environment-variables.sh && echo $TEST_PARAMETER"
  sudo bash -c "~/Environment/environment-variables.sh && echo $TEST_PARAMETER"
  sudo bash -c "source ~/Environment/environment-variables.sh && echo $TEST_PARAMETER"
  sudo bash <<< "source ~/Environment/environment-variables.sh && echo $TEST_PARAMETER"
';
```

How environment variables can be read from a file when going into a login shell with here-string and using the sudo command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment variable is set for ubuntu and not root you will need to use `sudo -E`

`-E` Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables

Comment: When I tried like this, it works, thanks: 
  source ~/Environment/environment-variables.sh
  sudo -E echo $TEST_PARAMETER